# Can I get separate URLs to FilterViews on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm treating a google sheet as a crude DB in which to dump details of all items in an issue-tracker (GitHub). A user can then add manual data in additional columns which must not get overwritten.

I want to set up different views e.g. one shows only open issues, one shows only bugs, etc.

It looks like Filter Views are the answer here but can I get an explicit URL to each one, to avoid my user having to figure them out? e.g. I can just say "this is the bug list URL"?

Comment: (if you think Filter Views are not the best option please mention an alternative in a comment, but reserve answers for the question asked)

Comment: Could you have two sheets?

Comment: I've no idea. How might that work?

Comment: Create a second sheet and query the first, since this is an open source sheet mind giving me access? I can have a quick look

Answer (score 1):

You can use `=QUERY` to filter on your range and pull out only the OPEN Issues.

You can share the URL with the link that goes straight to your 'OPEN' page.

Formula Used:

```
=Query(Sheet1!A:C, "Select * WHERE C = 'Open'")
```

[Sheet 1 - Master Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zHAyXMPH01Qfmpi7iHE8qt4EGGGUXmE5JiXpVOhbdsw/edit#gid=0)

[Sheet 2 - Open Issues.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zHAyXMPH01Qfmpi7iHE8qt4EGGGUXmE5JiXpVOhbdsw/edit#gid=668843320)

Comment: This is a really useful thing to know but I _think_ the addition to my post about users adding additional data will break it... if they add data in the 2nd sheet then the rows will 'move around' when a item changes state :(

Comment: Ii see, then I think an app script solution would be the best, you would need to write a script to progamatically hide or 'move' the data that meets a certain condition. I'd have a nose in SO. If you find a solution could you post it here? I'd love to know as well.